# inicio de sesion con google mediante firebase inicia siempre con la misma cuenta

Tags: reactjs

estoy usando firebase para una aplicacion web, tengo dos rutas para la authenticacion, una para iniciar y otra para registrar al usuario, el problema esta que cuando intento registrar una nueva cuenta de google, este automaticamente inicia sesion con la primer cuenta que se inicio, es un gran error ya que no me deja agregar un usuario nuevo de google, les dejo mi codigo

```
<TooltipCustom TransitionComponent={Zoom} title="GOOGLE">
     <IconButton style={{margin: '0px 1rem'}} onClick={() => { signupSocial("google") }}>
          <img
             src={require("./../../assets/svg/google.svg")}
             alt="registrate con google"
             className={classes.iconSocial}
          />
     </IconButton>
</TooltipCustom>
```

la funcion `signupSocial` la traigo desde un archivo donde guardo el contexto de la aplicacion, dentro de este contexto guardo los datos del usaurio y varias cosas mas indespensbles para que la aplicacion funcione, unas de ellas es la funcion para iniciar sesion con google, les dejo el codigo

```
const signupSocial = async (socialName)=>{
switch (socialName) {
  case "facebook":
    try {
      var providerFacebook = new fi.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();
      await firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(providerFacebook)
    } catch (error) {
      return error.code
    }
  case "google":
    try {
      var providerGoogle = new fi.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
      await firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(providerGoogle)
    } catch (error) {
      return error.code
    }
  }
}
```

el inicio de sesion lo hace normalmente, el problema esta en que si entran a la aplicacion por primera vez y se registrar con google, ala hora de salir y querer entrara con otra cuenta este ingresa con la cuenta que ya se registro, espero puedan ayudarme